# How do I use multiple copy & paste of non-contiguous text?

Tags: firefox, multiple-instances, cut-and-paste

I often need to select multiple lines of text and save them as a note in Firefox using some of the note taking add ons, such as Scrapbook, Evernote or Memonic. The problem is that it doesn't work with either of these and I get only the part I've first selected saved, while the other non-contiguous parts which I selected using Ctrl key are not being saved in a note. Then I need to save every selection separately, while I'd like to have them saved as a single note. Here's an example for illustration:[image]

As is shown in the picture I've selected three non-contiguous chunks of text, and I'd like to save them as a single note. Instead I get only the first selection saved "Una pregunda,tengo un texto..", while the other two are left out.

Any idea how I could resolve this problem using some of these add-ons or maybe some other similar Firefox extension.